# Получение значения статического поля через родительский класс

Tags: c++

Есть родительский класс `Base`, от него наследуются классы `Child1`, `Child2`.
В классах `Child1`, `Child2` есть статическое поле, значение поля для каждого дочернего класса разное.
Как можно реалиовать метод получения этого поля через класс `Base`?

**Updated**
Пример кода c виртуальными методами:

```
class Base
{
public:
    virtual int getField() = 0;
};

class Child1 : public Base
{
public:
    virtual int getField() { return s_field; };
private:
    static int s_field;
};

class Child2 : public Base
{
public:
    virtual int getField() { return s_field; };
private:
    static int s_field;  
};

int Child1::s_field = 1;
int Child2::s_field = 2;
```

Comment: виртуальным методом. (если тип одинаковый). Лучше бы привели пример как вы всё сделали.

Comment: @ AlexGlebe, сделал как раз виртуальными методами, но пример упрощен, дочерних классов может быть много, хотелось бы реализовать одной функцией через базовый класс `Base`, а не писать в каждом дочернем классе функцию-гетер.

Comment: На Си когда нибудь писали? Создаёте глобальный массив или map. Ключ будет тип объекта из enum или ключ из map пары. Одна функция будет извлекать из массива значение и всё. Будет очень сложно контролировать вручную этот список. Виртуальными будет проще.

Comment: Задавайте вопрос  с  примером кода, чтобы на ваш вопрос не отвечали вопросом.     Если типы статических полей одинаковы, то можно иметь это поле как защищенный член базового класса, а в дочерных изменять их значение.  И таких если не должно быть....

Comment: @AR Hovsepyan, пример кода добавил в вопрос, типы полей совпадают.
Можно пример кода вашего варианта?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Можно использовать [CRTP](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern).

```
struct GenericBase
{
    virtual int &GetField() const = 0;
};

template <typename T> struct Base : GenericBase
{
    int &GetField() const override
    {
        return T::s_field;
    }
};

struct Child1 : Base<Child1>
{
    inline static int s_field;
};

struct Child2 : Base<Child2>
{
    inline static int s_field;
};

int main()
{
    GenericBase *x = new Child1;
    x->GetField() = 1;
}
```

Здесь либо `s_field` должно быть `public`, либо `Base` должен быть `friend`-ом дочерних классов.

Если все `s_field` иницициализируются одинаково, можно вообще переместить `s_field` в `Base` (поскольку `Base` - шаблон, у каждого дочернего класса будет свой `s_field`).

Также, если вам не нужен полиморфизм, в принципе можно убрать `GenericBase`.

Comment: Прикольный шаблон. Исправьте, плиз, опечатку `struct Child2 : Base<Child1>`

Comment: @cassius Поправил.

Answer (score 1):

Так как у каждого экземпляра, только одно статическое поле.

```
class Base
{
public:
    Base(int * p):p_s_field(p){}
    int getField()const {return * p_s_field;}
private:
    // указатель на нужный экземпляр статического поля
    int * p_s_field;
};

class Child1 : public Base
{
public:
    Child1():Base(&Child1::s_field){}
private:
    static int s_field;
};

class Child2 : public Base
{
public:
    Child2():Base(&Child2::s_field){}
private:
    static int s_field;
};
int Child1::s_field = 1;
int Child2::s_field = 2;
```

Но это уже в стиле Си.

Answer (score 0):

Классы являются наследниками одного и того же класса и содержат статические поля одного и того же типа. Это именно тот случай, когда нужно иметь только защищенный( если удобней, то открытый) член в базовом классе, тогда все производные классы могут изменять его значение по своему усмотрению. Например:

```
class Base
{
protected:
    static int s_field;
public:
    static int get_static_data() { return s_field; }
    //...
};
int Base::s_field;
class Child1 : public Base{   
public:
    Child1() { this->s_field = 1; }
    //...    
};

class Child2 : public Base
{
public:
    Child2() { this->s_field = 2; }
    //...
};
//некоторая функция
void show_static_data(const Base& b)
{
    std::cout << b.get_static_data() << std::endl;
    //...
}
int main() {    
    show_static_data(Child1());     
    show_static_data(Child2());
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: В этом случае используется одна статическая переменная, т.е. если класс `Child2` изменит ее значение, то и для класса `Child1` значение изменится.

Comment: @cassius, правильно, но в вопросе нет обратного утверждения